# Как правильно подключить несколько контроллеров Laravel

Tags: laravel

У меня есть `header`, `navbar`  и `content`, у каждого из них есть свой контроллер.

Как правильно сделать так что бы `headerController` и `NavbarController` подключались всегда при любом роуте, а `ContentController` менялся в зависимости от того какой роут выбран?

Comment: вы говорите про js контроллеры? задайте разные шаблоны + подключение контроллера по передаваемой в шаблон переменной

Comment: Нет я говорил про обычные контроллеры Laravel:

Comment: Нет я говорил про обычные контроллеры Laravel: вот например у меня есть файл `index.balde.php` - вот я в нем подключаю файлы шаблонов `@include('header.head')
@include('header.header')

@include('nav.navbar')

 @yield('content')

@include('footer.footer')`  , а вот в других файлах(`dashboard.index`-> `@extends('index')

@section('content')`) я вызываю этот файл получается и я хотел бы чтобы контроллеры(`HeaderController` и `NavController`) видов `'header.header'` и  `'nav.navbar'` отрабатывали и выдавали свои переменные во вьюху.

Comment: Либо мои знания дико устарели, либо вы чего-то непонимаете. Контроллеры в ларавел вызываются по роуту, вы конечно можете перекидываться из одного контроллера в другой через return, но это какое-то извращение. В вашем случае правильнее будет в базовом контроллере, от которого наследуются все остальные, объявить все нужные переменные, либо глобально присваивать переменные для шаблона. Вообще не обязательно объявлять все переменные в контроллере, что-то вроде Auth::user() можно выполнять и в шаблоне чтобы упростить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контроллеры предназачены для обработки URL запросов, но некак не для представлений. MVC - как раз и говорит о явном разделении системы на модель, представление и контроллер.

Ты можешь создать папку `app/layouts` с классами:

- Header.php
- Content.php
- Navbar.php

И в представление передавать их:

```
@extends('layout.header', ['header' => (new \App\Layouts\Header)])
```

И уже в конструкторе класса получать необходимые данные из `routes()` с которыми ты бы хотел работать в контроллере.

Comment: Спасибо, это именно тот ответ который я хотел услышать!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь :)